# SAS presentation of observation in different format

Tags: sas

How to present observation in different formats in a variable in sas is it possible. For ex the name of variable is salary first observation should be 23499 second should be 34% it should be in % format not in text

Thanks

Comment: Where are you displaying this? If you want observations to look different in a viewtable window without formatting as text I don't think that's possible, but there may be other options if you are displaying the variable via proc report etc.

Answer (score 0):

A programatically solution would be to cast the numbers in chars and format it according to the row they appear, e.G.:

```
data y;

set x;

if _N_ = 1 then
num=put(numb, 5.);
else if _n_ = 2 then
num =put( numb/100, percent.);
else
num=put(numb, 3.);

run;

proc print data=y;
run;
```

with a dataset

```
23499
34
23
2433
```

this would lead to this result in print:

```
numb   num 
23499 23499 
 34    34% 
 23    23 
2433   2E3
```